# Fastest scaleable Database for "goup by, count" Queries

Tags: database, analytics, nosql

We search for a fast and scaleable analytics Database to host in Amazon Cloud for Queries like

"select value, count(*) from table group by value"

We testet a lot of Analytics and Data Warehouse solutions but we didnt find the one we need :(

There are all to slow on Tables with ~ 50mio Records.

Tested:

- Redshift
- RDS(MySQL, Oracle, Postgres)
- Clustrix

Comment: It depends on how you test it as to how well it works. Shouldn't an index make this extremely fast?

Comment: the problem is that the most DBs make Tablescans to get the count(*). So Index doesnt help?

Comment: Databases do not do table scan for such a query especially Redshift which is primarily a columnar DB .Can you please provide some more details as to what HW did you use and how much data (in TB or Gb) you were running this query on? What sort of time are you expecting and what times are you getting on the query. This aggregate query should be extremely fast if data is not skewed. I can help further if you can please provide some more details. thanks

Comment: Hey @FrankyK, I work at ClustrixDB and wanted to know -- which version of Clustrix did you test and what kind of results are you looking for? We actually have some performance optimizations to count(*) queries in a new release that hasn't yet been released to the marketplace yet.

Answer (score 0):

@FrankyK

Clustrix(Scale-Out RDB) has hash_aggregate_partial & combine for scale-out aggregation in the Execution Plan. (Every nodes and cpus could work parallelly in the nature of NewSQL. Check how many slices for the table in how many nodes and cpus. It needs right usage). For your query 'group by value', You should have tested 'dist_stream_aggregate' with an index including the column 'value'. It is even much faster for your case than hash_aggregate_partial.

Keep in mind that the skewness and NDV of 'value' may impacts on the GROUP BY performance. In my real tests, I found that ClutrixDB definitely 
 could beat against ORACLE, MySQL (even though Oracle has both Parallel Processing and Multi-Block I/O - Full Table Scan and Full Index Scan) under the situation over 200 millions rows (It means the number of rows and sizes fit for Scale-Out).